# SCCM Update Storage - Large and duplicated?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus, sccm, sccm-2012-r2

Can anyone help me understand why my Update Group Storage is so large?  I have enabled dedupe on the volume as a quick fix.  Why are my updates making copies every time my update group runs?  Specifically, Windows Defender is 33.6 GB (deduped down to 4.19 as the image shows).

Is it due to the Auto Deployment rule?  I have it set to create a new group.  Should i have manually created a group and let it use an existing group?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruExF.jpg

I am rather new to SCCM so I hope that it is something stupid that I am missing.

EDIT:  Still not fixed, if anyone happens to come across this in the future.  Dedupe has been my only working bandaid.

Comment: How many ADR groups do you have?

Comment: Just 3.  One for Defender, Win7, and Win10.

Comment: Cant edit it appears, but i have 4... Win7, 8, 10, and Defender.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, some expired updates caused the large size, please try to delete them manually or by script.

[Software Update Content Cleanup in System Center 2012 Configuration Manager](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2012/04/12/software-update-content-cleanup-in-system-center-2012-configuration-manager/)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Didnt think of that...  I will give that a shot and see if my storage usage decreases.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you chose to download / deploy all of the updates in the history of defender.

I would verify the ADR definition only is releasing updates released or revised in the last day. There is no reason to download them all.

[image: ADR - Date filter]

I would check the language setting on the ADR and make sure only the required lanugages are selected.
[image: ADR language]

A Microsoft partner has created [this handy script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Remove-Expired-Superseded-f35495e1) to clear out expired and superseded updates.

Comment: I know right off of the bat that i did not use the Date Released/Revised filter...  Looking into this all now....  Will update soon.

Comment: Slight update - I added the date released to my filter, but that didnt seem to change anything.  Today alone, i have 1.38GB (545 items) in my Defender update storage location.  I am fearing it is how i have the Automatic Update group creating a new software group instead of using an existing.

But thanks for that script!  Due to using multiple groups, i cant really use that (yet).  I am going to restructure my updates and manually create the update group and then let the Auto Deployment use that group.

Comment: Defender Updates Content Status now says 39GB.  I manually removed some old updates so they are physically down to 22GB  (4.85GB with Dedupe).

Thanks, but the filter didnt help much (if at all).